# What is the application/vnd.github+json media type?

Tags: github-api, media-type

I was going through [Github REST API v3 doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/media/) and found the media type `application/vnd.github+json`. I am familiar with traditional media types such as `application/json`, `application/xml`.

It seems to be that it is related to OpenAPI 3 specification. If I were to create my own media type, how would I go about creating one for a new a team which would be used by other teams?

Answer (score 10):

I believe application/vnd.github+json is just the **custom** media type that is used for the Github api. The difference being that application/vnd.github+json allows to specify the api version and the format of the data being returned. Having a custom media type is useful for versioning an api and is why this was made in the first place.

Comment: How can I create a custom media type myself?